# Sylow $p$-subgroup is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=p^{\alpha}m$, and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $x\in P$ is such that $x$ has order $p$ and that $C_{G}(x)$ has cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroups. Then $P$ is cyclic.

My attempt (edited):

If $x\not\in Z(P)$, choose $y\in Z(P)$ of order $p$. Such $y$ exists since $Z(P)\supsetneq \{1\}$. Then $yxy^{-1}x^{-1}=1$, so that $yx=xy$. Since $\langle x\rangle\cap \langle y\rangle\leq\langle y\rangle$, then $\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle$ is either trivial or $\langle y\rangle$. It cannot be the latter for otherwise $x\in\langle y\rangle\subseteq Z(P)$, a contradiction. Hence $\langle x,y\rangle\cong\langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup of $C_{G}(x)$ and so is cyclic by hypothesis.

Comments (edited):

1. I have a feeling that I should conclude that $\langle x,y\rangle$ is not cyclic, but I am not sure how to.
2. With this $\langle x,y\rangle$ not being cyclic, we get a contradiction so that $x\in Z(P)$. How then would we be able to conclude that $P\subseteq C_{G}(x)$ as I feel that it should go in this direction.

I would appreciate any hints to point me in the right direction for this problem.

Comment: You have not justified your statement that $|C_G(x)| = p^\beta m$, and it is not correct in general. You should use the fact that $Z(P)$ is nontrivial and that $C_G(x)$ contains $Z(P)$.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped that. Edited it to $m_{0}$ instead. I will try to work using the hint.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have edited the question using your hint and I am now stuck once again (the answer would be too long to read in this comment). Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that I can help you any more with this. It follows immediately from $\langle x,y \rangle \cong \langle x \rangle \times \langle y \rangle$ that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is not cyclic. And $x \in Z(P)$ implies immediately (it doesn't require any explanation at all) that $P \le C_G(x)$.

Comment: Ah yes, I realised it is indeed direct from the definition of $C_{G}(x)$. Thank you so much.